# How to filter a list in an excel sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have to filter below given excel sheet by a list of 'ID's.
[image: Table to be sorted]

My excel sheet contains thousands of 'ID', in which i have to filter only a particular list of 'ID's. It will take time if I enter values in the list one by one, now how can i filter the list of 'ID's at a time? For example in the above excel sheet how can I filter the list {3,4,11,19}?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Data > Advanced Filter to filter the list. You need to enter the filter criteria in one or more cells. These cells must have the same column header as the column you want to filter on. Typically, these filter criteria cells are created in empty rows above the table, but they can be anywhere else on the spreadsheet.

Click a cell in the data table, select Data > Advanced Filter. Select the filter range and tick to filter the list in place.

[image]

The result looks like this:

[image]

Note how the blue row headers indicate that there are hidden rows. You can clear the filter by hitting the "Clear" button on the ribbon.

Comment: Thanks, can I use "criteria range" present in another sheet of same book(i checked it, but it's not possible, is there any way to do this)?

Comment: The criteria range has to be in the same sheet. But you could use formulas or other techniques to get them there.

Answer (score 1):

In general you wouldn't be filtering on a list of ID, the whole idea of ID's is for a unique identifier for each row of data making it unique from each other.

You would normally have other columns of "category", "sub category" etc to make the data meaningful.

But saying that , you can use vba to allow you to enter a list of numbers to filter for you.

Create an input box where you enter a list of comma separated values

use vba to create an array of these numbers ,

then set the auto filter with

```
Criteria1:=Array(var1,var2,var3,var4,etc, "=")
```

Answer (score 1):

The drawback of Advanced Filter is that you can't display the filter or update it. Each time you want to update it, you must define the Advanced Filter from scratch.

Another solution (which also has some drawbacks) is to create a new filtered range with a formula like this one (inspired from [this one-column solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66251058/9150270)):

```
=FILTER(A6:D25,NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A6:A25,Sheet1!A1:A4,0))),"")
```

Example:

[image: Excel Filter Match]