# Filter values from a list using values in another list

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, filter, excel-formula

I have example data in the image shown, that uses the formula:

```
=FILTER(B3:B13,(B3:B13<>"D")*(B3:B13<>"H")*(B3:B13<>"J"))
```

to filter A-K such that D,H and J are removed from the returned list.

Is there any way using a formula that instead of having to specify the letters I wish to be removed can omit the values listed in another column (A in this case)? Ideally the solution will be just a formula but VBA could work too if anyone knows a solution for this.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ISERROR(MATCH()):

```
=FILTER(B3:B13,ISERROR(MATCH(B3:B13,A:A,0)))
```

[image]